# Is there a "Switch User" functionality in Windows that doesn't require switching users?

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-instances, multiple-users, resources

**For Example**:

I'm working on 2 massive projects on a PC with limited screen real-estate and resources and would like to easily be able to switch between the 2 projects, without having to close and re-open programs and hide show certain windows (as needed to free resources or show proper open programs).

**Explaining Further**:

Does Windows have anything like the “Switch User” (Windows -> Shutdown -> Switch User) option, **but** without requiring a secondary account or sign in.

We’d keep the functionality of hiding, closing and opening windows and resources based on user signed in?

Comment: Would this help you:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/desktops

Comment: SICK! thanks @HelpingHand feel free to answer, I'll mark it as such

Comment: Also note, that in Windows 10, this functionality is [built in](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028538/windows-10-multiple-desktops).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your operating system, Desktops by Microsoft may well prove useful.  This tool can be downloaded from:

https://docs.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/desktops

On Windows 10, see: https://support.microsoft.com/help/4028538/windows-10-multiple-desktops for similar functionality.